# Something $= \infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\alpha$ be the number of solutions of certain equation. I want to say that the number of solutions are infinite. Can I write $\alpha = \infty$ or is it wrong to write that?

Comment: Infinity is not a number in usual number system, so it is better for you to just write "there are infinite solutions to the equation"

Comment: It is not wrong, but it is quite unusual and inaccurate. $\alpha$ denotes a cardinality, while the symbol $\infty$ does not (it could be $\aleph_0 , \aleph_1 $ or whatsoever). Anyway, when you introduce the symbol $\alpha$, you may say that $\alpha = \infty$ is the same as saying that there are infinitely many solutions. This is not wrong, since you are simply introducing a notation.

Comment: I second what Crostul said. This isn't technically wrong, but I would suggest avoiding this notation. It's better to simply say "the solution set is infinite".

Comment: @Crostul Got it, thanks. I'll stick with 'there are infinitely many solutions'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have written is not wrong, but the notation is really uncomfortable. By uncomfortable I mean to say that what you are representing is the cardinality of a set which contains solutions to a certain equation . Now as Crostul says there are many kind of infinities and someone looking at it might not (countably infinite, uncountably infinite) understand what you are trying to convey